# Cut Custom Shape into Side of Cylinder

Tags: modeling, topology, subdivision-surface, knife-tool

I am trying to model a [British Sterling L2A3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterling_submachine_gun) & I'm having serious issues with modeling the ejection port. The main body of the weapon is a cylinder with many different types of cuts, and I normally approach them with Knife Projecting the shape into the cylinder, then bridging the vertices and adding a few edge loops. In this case I end up with a lot of distortions.

With the cut I am also trying to add that half-cylindrical shape on the right end of the ejection port, as shown in the image. I have been at this for days and I simply cannot find a solution that ensures neat and clean topology.

[.blend File](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ppatjvh3vtipcrj/brit_sterling.blend/file)

[image]

[image]